# Audio HTML5 Autoplay WebWorks

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

How does one get the HTML5 Audio tag to work in a webworks app with the Autoplay option?

Ex:
On document load Audio element's src changed via javascript then audioElement.play() - this doesn't work, you have to bind the click of another link or button to audioElement.play() and click AGAIN...

Any ideas?

```
function playSongNow(currentID) {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'true');
    audioElement.setAttribute('preload', 'true');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://' + sessionStorage.url + ':' + sessionStorage.port + '/rest/stream.view?u=' + sessionStorage.user + '&p=' + sessionStorage.pass + '&v=1.6.0&c=BerrySonic&id=' + currentID);
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement.play();
        $(".duration span").html(audioElement.duration);
        $(".filename span").html(audioElement.src);
    }, true);
    $('.play').click(function() {
        audioElement.play();
    });
    $('.pause').click(function() {
        audioElement.pause();
    });
    $('.volumeMax').click(function() {
        audioElement.volume=1;
    });
    $('.volumestop').click(function() {
        audioElement.volume=0;
    });
    $('.stop').click(function() {
        audioElement.pause();
        audioElement.currentTime = 0;
    });
    $('.playatTime').click(function() {
        audioElement.currentTime= 35; //Testing skipping so used 35
        audioElement.play();
    });
}
```

playSongNow is called by the HTML:

```
<a onclick="playSongNow('2f6d656469612f52616964426f782f4d757369632f4164656c652f32312f4164656c65202d2052756d6f7572204861732049742e6d7033');"><li>Rumour Has It</li></a>
```

**NEW: Actually I think I've narrowed the issue down to :**

```
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.play();
    $(".duration span").html(audioElement.duration);
    $(".filename span").html(audioElement.src);
}, true);
```

I tried using "canplaythrough"
But neither works to determine when enough data has passed in to actually play because if you do:

```
audioElement.load();
audioElement.play();
```

I tried the following event:

```
audioElement.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    alert('canplay');
    audioElement.play();
});
```

And this works but this doesn't mean that the audio can play without buffering does it? It also immidiately fires the "canplaythrough" event.

Some guidance on these events would be handy.

Comment: When and how is `playSongNow(currentID)` called?

Comment: Please see updated code to indicate how its called. Thanks!

Comment: Are you appending this audio to the body? If not, why?

Comment: Actually I think I've narrowed the issue down to :
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
});
I tried using "oncanplaythrough"
But neither works to determine when enough data has passed in to actually play because if you do:

audioElement.load();
audioElement.play();

Then the audio works. This leaves me a little bit high/dry because the user is cannot be given feedback on when i'm loading.

Comment: No real need to append to body is there? It seems to work without it - the controls etc are being done manually, I suppose I could append to body but I don't especially see why i need to.

Comment: Added new code due to further debugging, please end of question. Thanks!

Please also answer the question so I may reward as it seems we are getting mighty close to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this with the `ended` event like the following :

```
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function(){
playSongNow(......)
}, false);
```

Comment: Sorry for the earlier comment - you are right - the ended event does fire, but the canplaythrough never fires. So it seems my problems exists still.

Comment: Yeah i think you have to set the time to zero first , pause , and finally play again .


this.currentTime = 0;
this.pause();
playSongNow(......)

Comment: Just playing the song can be done now but without any indication the song is loading or done loading etc - please see updates question.

Comment: Can you provide me the source code with any testing audio file ?

Comment: That really is all the source - the rest is zepto (or jQuery if you prefer as I haven't used anything zepto specific) - the audio file is also just another random mp3.

Answer (score 0):

canplaythrough doesn't fire on blackberries but canplay does....don't ask me why....